# Laravel: Cannot get parent of a category

Tags: php, laravel, model, eloquent, relation

I am working on a classified ads platform and i am having a problem with a relation. Although i think i've set up everything right there is still this issue.

**The scenario is this:**
I have a model ***Category*** (App\Category) with the folowing relations to form the subcategories

```
class Category extends Model
{
    public function parent() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Category', 'parent_id');
    }

    public function children() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Category', 'parent_id');
    }

    public function adverts() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Advert');
    }

}
```

I also have a model ***Advert*** (App\Advert) with the following relations

```
class Advert extends Model
{

    public function category() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Category');
    }

    public function user() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }

}
```

And finally I have a model ***User*** (App\Advert) with the following relations

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    public function adverts() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Advert');
    }
}
```

I am collecting the adverts in a collection within a controller like this

```
$adverts = $user->adverts()->with('category')->with('category.parent')->get();
```

The problem i am facing is when i try to output the adverts and the category they belong along with the corresponding subcategory i am experiencing this issue

```
Trying to get property of non-object (View: 
..\resources\views\user\profile.blade.php)
```

On the following line

```
$ad->category->parent->name . ' / ' . $ad->category->name
```

When i dd the collection i can see all the adverts and the relations together with the category and the subcategory ... but when i try to output it like this i got this error **Trying to get property of non-object**

Help anyone?
Thanks

Comment: hmm this seems that you are getting a collection OR you have to make sure that a user has a category meaning you maybe have users that doesn't have any advert. try to iterrate the $ad in blade. btw you can use $adverts = $user->adverts()->with('category','category.parent')->get();

Comment: It looks like you're having a advert without a category or a category without a parent. For the syntax you can just use `->with('category.parent')`, this will also load the category. You could also look at `whereHas` to make sure you only fetch adverts with a category or use `with('category', function()...`.

Comment: Do all off your categories have a parent? When one doesn't, that's the problem. In that case you first have to check if the category has a parent and then display it's name.

Comment: You sure you have an array of models else you have to access the data like $data["your_value"]; or something simular. Try $ad->category->parent[0]->name or $ad->category->parent[0]["name"] maybe?

Comment: Ah ... this was such a begimners mistake... i didnt noticed that not all of the categories have parents ... my bad guys ... thanks for the help though

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this helps anything, but I am posting it as an answer to make the code more readable, thats all. Not expecting any credits ;)

In one of my models I set up the child / parents relationships like this:

```
/**
 * Get the Categories associated with the parent's `id`
 */
public function children()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Category', 'parent_id', 'id');
}

/**
 * Get the parent associated with the Category`s parent_id`
 */
public function parent()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Category');
}
```